# Android ListView Integer array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an integer array into ListView using an adapter but do not seem to know where to begin. 
I want the user to be able to open the listview, select a number from 1-99 and have the selected number be deducted from the current year and result displayed in a TextView.

Any help in the right direction would be fantastic!

Comment: Hey, you can find some tutorials on youtube. Search for 'The New Boston'.

Comment: Thanks! I have heard differing opinions on those videos however they definitely are helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first you have to create xml of listview given below



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


make one arraylist<String> list=new arraylist<string>;
add value 1-99 using for loop
and then set the array adpter on that listview as like




package com.example.arraydemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ListView li;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        li=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        for(int i=1;i<=99;i++){
        list.add(""+i);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                list );

        li.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
        li.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }


}



and ontemclicklistener you get current date from system deduct position of listview from that date
```

Comment: So sorry for the delay on the thanks! But thank you for helping me into the right direction. I am going to go work on this little program I want to build and see if I can get it to work.